# toggle display on hover table row with same class

Tags: jquery

I have a table that looks like:

```
<tr class="record"><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></tr>
<tr class="record"><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></tr>
<tr class="record"><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></tr>
<tr class="record"><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></tr>
<tr class="record"><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></tr>
```

The ".mi_dl_ro_w1" is by default (display:none) and it's fixed positioned on the page.

What I'm trying to achieve is: when HOVER on the tr.record, the .mi_dl_ro_w1 of the HOVERED tr.record must become display:block...

Here is what I've tried so far but it doesn't seem to work :(

```
jQuery('.record').on('mouseover', function (evt) {
          var $button = jQuery(this);
          var $tr = $button.parents('tr');
              var $div = $tr.find('.mi_dl_ro_w1');
              $div.toggle();
});
```

Can somebody please give me a hand on this? Thank you very much

Comment: sorry stupid mistake:) change it to class :) But it still doesn't work :(

Comment: You can't have a `<div>` as a child of a `<tr>`. Only `<td>` or `<th>` can be a child of a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('.record').on('mouseover', function (evt) {
          jQuery(this).find('.mi_dl_ro_w1').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the id of the divs must be unique. You can replace id="mi_dl_ro_w1" with class="mi_dl_ro_w1".

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.record td {height:10px; width:70px;}
.mi_dl_ro_w1 {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr class="record"><td><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></td></tr>
<tr class="record"><td><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></td></tr>
<tr class="record"><td><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></td></tr>
<tr class="record"><td><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></td></tr>
<tr class="record"><td><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></td></tr>
<tr class="record"><td><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></td></tr>
<tr class="record"><td><div class="mi_dl_ro_w1">some text</div></td></tr>
</table>
<script>
$('.record').hover(
    function() {
        miToggle($(this));
    },
    function() {
        miToggle($(this));
    }
);
function miToggle(element) {
    if($(element).hasClass('record') || $(element).closest('tr').hasClass('record')) {
        $(element).find('.mi_dl_ro_w1').toggle();
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `hover`

```
$(".record").hover(
function () {
    $(this).find('.mi_dl_ro_w1').show();
},
function () {
    $(this).find('.mi_dl_ro_w1').hide();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/L8qz4/)**